# django-cms and error with CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF

Tags: python, django, django-cms

in my project I have this error:

"
File "/home/xxx/www/yyy/cms/utils/placeholder.py", line 43, in validate_placeholder_name
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Placeholder identifiers names may not "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Placeholder identifiers names may not contain non-ascii characters. If you wish your placeholder identifiers to contain non-ascii characters when displayed to users, please use the CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF setting with the 'name' key to specify a verbose name.
"

My settings.py hasn't got any CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF, so it is default {} - an empty dict.

Any idea why I have error and I could not have default settings?

Comment: could you show the template code ?

Comment: in template i have: {% render_placeholder content %}  - where content in models.py is:
 
content = PlaceholderField(_(u'Content'), help_text="Plugins")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in this line

```
content = PlaceholderField(_(u'Content'), help_text="Plugins")
```

you can't pass a translatable string as the placeholder name(slot) simply because one of the translations could have a non-ascii character, not to mention the multiple problems that will arise since the string is used as an identifier. Here's what I would do:

```
content = PlaceholderField(u'content', help_text="Plugins")
```

and then add the proper translatable string in the configuration for the placeholder which allows you to give a more human readable name and also have it in different languages using the django translations framework:

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'content': {
        'name': gettext("Content"),
    },
}
```